# How can I find a specific record in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

Let's say that I have a `Cursor` that has 50 records in it and it is bound to a `ListView` using a `ViewBinder`.  I'd like to find a specific row(example: `_id` 35) and make sure that record is visible to the user on the android device.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What is `find a specific row`? You can call `Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position)` to get a cursor pointing to the position the user selected.  Then you can retrieve the data like `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("columnName"))`.